# Python: check whether a word is spelled correctly

Tags: python, spell-checking

I'm looking for a an easy way to check whether a certain string is a correctly-spelled English word. For example, 'looked' would return True while 'hurrr' would return False. I don't need spelling suggestions or any spelling-correcting features. Just a simple function that takes a string and returns a boolean value.

Comment: Hunspell check is very famous, Try its python wrapper. https://datascience.blog.wzb.eu/2016/07/13/autocorrecting-misspelled-words-in-python-using-hunspell/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Two possible ways of doing it:

1. Have your own file which has all the
   valid words. Load the file into a
   set and compare each word to see
   whether it exists in it (word in set)
2. (The better way) Use [PyEnchant](https://github.com/rfk/pyenchant), a spell checking library for Python

PyEnchant is not actively maintained now.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I did while waiting for an answer ;)

Comment: Use a set rather than a list, and ask `if word in my_set` for better performance.

Comment: @Karl: A very valid point indeed, sets are significantly faster than lists when it comes to determining if an object is present in the set or not. Updated.

Comment: PyEnchant is an excellent suggestion!

Comment: Instead of list or set, I'll go for [trie tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for the same functionality and struggled to find an existing library that works in Windows, 64 bit. PyEnchant, although a great library, isn't currently active and doesn't work in 64 bit. Other libraries I found didn't work in Windows.

I finally found a solution that I hope others will find valuable.

The solution...

- Use nltk
- Extract the word list from nltk.corpus.brown
- Convert the word list to a set (for efficient searching)
- Use the `in` keyword to determine if your string is in the set

---

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
word_list = brown.words()
word_set = set(word_list)

# Check if word is in set
"looked" in word_set  # Returns True
"hurrr" in word_set  # Returns False
```

Use a timer check and you'll see this takes virtually no time to search the set. A test on 1,000 words took 0.004 seconds.

Comment: Missing a lot of not terribly uncommon words, e.g. reuse, gleams, cue etc.

Answer (score 4):

I personally used: http://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/
It is an active project and according to the website:

Spelling correction is based on Peter Norvig’s “How to Write a Spelling Corrector”[1] as implemented in the pattern library. It is about 70% accurate

Comment: Textblob is super cool! in installation, usage, documentation. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo provides spell checking [API](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/web/V1/spellingSuggestion.html) through YQL.

Its pretty simple and you get 5000 queries/ip address/day for non-commercial use (FREE)