# Is there any way to do spell check in textarea using robotics framework

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

Text area got from web page:

our feedback will definitely help us, thanks for writing. Regret that the product was damaged.  Serving our customers is our first priority.  We take the unconditional responsibility in terms of packaging our products. We apologize for the trouble created to you with regards to the packaging.

I need to run a spell checker on the complete text area

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done any research on existing robot framework libraries that provide spell checking? Have you researched on python libraries that do spell checking so that you can write your own keywords?

Answer (score 1):

No matter what programming language you are using, but basically it's the question of finding a spell checker. With a spell checker library, you can define your own library, so as to perform the spell check.

So, the steps would be:

1. Find a spell checker library:
   E.g.: [Python: check whether a word is spelled correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500752/python-check-whether-a-word-is-spelled-correctly)
2. Create your own function to do the spell check (this should be easy)
3. In your robot framework, import above custom library

Hope this helps.